# Why grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle still keeps right keys as switch triggers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, xkb

I ran the following command in my terminal:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option "grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle,ctrl:nocaps"
```

but for some reason, the effect is the same if I specified "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle" - both `Left-Shift+Left-Ctrl` and `Right-Shift+Right-Ctrl` change my layout. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably it is a remaining of a *previous* configuration
If you want to ensure there are no previous options remaining, use `-option` (that is, an empty option instruction).

If I set:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option -option "grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle,ctrl:nocaps"
```

then I can switch with <kbd>LShift</kbd>-<kbd>LCtrl</kbd> and <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> does not.